My iMac Magic Keyboard is dead
My imac Magic Keyboard is dead and won’t take a charge. Have had it plugged in to recharge it for hours, still nothing. Do the batteries in these die after awhile?

How old is the keyboard? Did you try a different cable/charger?

About 4 years. I’ve tried different outlets and cables to no avail

We had one of these do spicy pillows when the batteries in it failed, so it's not unheard of them to fail.

@MarcWilson "Do Spicy pillows"..? Had to look that one up!  == "swell".

Problem solved I think. Plugged the keyboard directly into the back of the computer to charge it and it came alive right away. Kept it charging for a long time and then used it to update iOS to latest version. It now it works again. Not sure what happened but back in business
